# Getting rid of terminal when running pygame under Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pygame

When running pygame in Ubuntu a terminal is opened along with the pygame window. I want to get rid of the terminal. I can launch pygame with `nohup` and `&`:

```
$ nohup python3 mygame.py &
```

This allows the terminal to be closed, but it does not prevent it from being opened in the first place.

Is there a way to run pygame without a terminal being opened?

Comment: You could try using: `exec  python3 mygame.py` , but I suspect python could still need the terminal.

Comment: how do you run it ? Do you create shortcut on desktop ? Maybe shortcut run it in terminal . On Linux Mint (Mate/Gnome) I can create shortcut with or without terminal.

Comment: or maybe you should set `chmod +x mygame.py` and add `shebang` in first line `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and Linux will tread it as executable program.

Comment: @furas Aha. I was launching it from the Geany editor, which seems to be opening the terminal. I created a desktop shortcut, and the terminal went away. Thanks.

Comment: Many editors/IDE open terminal to run code (not only in Python) - it is very useful when program uses `print()` to display text, error message or other information useful to debug code.

Answer (score 0):

The OP explains that one should create a desktop shortcut,
and the the terminal goes away.